# ios - cannot access data from other view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, delegates

It's the first time I'm coding an Iphoneapp and i'm having some difficulties figuring out what i'm doing wrong here.

I have 2 view controllers: viewController and viewController2 I'm calling viewcontroller2 from viewController to set some parameters and access them in viewController.

I use the delegate pattern for this, as below :

In viewController2.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ViewController2Delegate
-(void)setVideoQual:(NSInteger)quality; 
@end


@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;
@property IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *videoQuality;

-(IBAction)handleCloseButton:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)updateVideoQuality:(UISegmentedControl *)sender;

@end
```

Basically, I want to access the quality I set with the function setVideoQual in viewController. I set the quality using a UISegmentedControl.

In viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@implementation ViewController2
@synthesize delegate;
-(IBAction)updateVideoQuality:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"change video quality: %ld", (long)sender.selectedSegmentIndex);


}
-(IBAction)handleCloseButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate setVideoQual:_videoQuality.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
@end
```

in viewController.h I have a property named VIDEOQUALITY that I want to set to quality imported from viewController2:

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
 ...
NSInteger VIDEOQUALITY;
}

...

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger VIDEOQUALITY;


@end
```

Then in viewController.m I have :

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize VIDEOQUALITY;


#pragma mark - UI Actions

- (IBAction)actionStart:(id)sender;
{
    ...
    NSLog(@"NEW VIDEO QUALITY: %d", VIDEOQUALITY);
    ...

}
-(void)setVideoQual:(NSInteger)quality
{
    NSLog(@"SETTING VIDEO QUALITY %ld",quality);
    VIDEOQUALITY=quality;
   }


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ViewController2 *ViewController2 = [segue destinationViewController];
    ViewController2.delegate = self;
}
@end
```

I cannot figure out why when I call actionStart the value of VIDEOQUALITY is never set to the value it appears to be set to when setvideoQual function was called ?

Comment: Why are you using a pointer for VIDEOQUALITY? Also why is it all caps

Comment: @RichTolley: Yes I changed it but the problem is still the same. The setVideoQual function is called, and the the viewDidLoad function is called and it's like the VIDEOQUALITY goes back to 0 .

Comment: Is any other method changing the variable?

Comment: Also, your delegate should be `@property (nonatomic,weak)` not `retain`. But I don't think that's the problem. Check it isn't nil in the delegate call anyway

Comment: And also check you've hooked up the segmented control as well

Comment: @RichTolley I looked up in the code, and there is no other occurence of this variable, I'm wondering If something is setting it to 0 "implicitely" when viewDidload is called. In my log I get : SETTING VIDEO QUALITY 2 / NEW VIDEO QUALITY 0, so I think the segmented control worked fine. I'm gonna change the retain and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why have you declared `NSInteger* VIDEOQUALITY;` as pointer? It seems like you don't need this, 'cause `NSInteger` is *primitive* type and is defined as unsigned `int NSUInteger`(for example). 
I think if you change you declaration to

```
{
   NSInteger VIDEOQUALITY;
}
...

@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger VIDEOQUALITY;
```

and implementation to

```
-(void)setVideoQual:(NSInteger)quality
{
    NSLog(@"SETTING VIDEO QUALITY %ld",quality);
    VIDEOQUALITY=quality;
}
```

you'll get desired behaviour.

Comment: the problem is still the same, after setVideoQual is called, the viewdidload function is called and then I don't know why VIDEOQUALITY goes back to 0...

Comment: @RickyBobby in handleCloseButton: method you call `[self.delegate setVideoQual:_videoQuality.selectedSegmentIndex];` and that's why you get 0 in VIDEOQUALITY variable(if first segment of control is selected). What do you try to achieve by this code?

Comment: even if I select another index I still get 0 and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: @RickyBobby do you assign `VIDEOQUALITY=quality;` only once in your code (in setVideoQual:)? Maybe you didn't provide here complete implementation of class and assign the value to this variable somewhere else. Check if there are other places where VIDEOQUALITY could be set.

Comment: I created a new variable named qual2, and I still get the same issue. It's like these variables are implicitely set to 0 at one point in time.

Comment: Maybe your ViewController somehow is recreated? Try to add in setVideoQual: method `NSLog(@"self in setVideoQual: %p", self);` and in actionStart: method add `NSLog(@"self in actionStart: %p", self);` 
You need this to check if you deal with same instance of ViewController. If you will get same addresses of memory - the problem isn't here.

Comment: Yes I that seems to be it, I gonna check why it would be recreated.